# Как использовать Pjax в Yii2 для построения формы?

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
<?php
/** @var ActiveForm $form */
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'selectAction'
]);
?>

<div class="page__wrapper">
    <input type="text"/>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'action')
        ->dropDownList([
            'sms' => 'Отправить SMS',
            'subscribe' => 'Подписка на контент'
        ]); ?>


    <?php 
    Pjax::begin([
        'id' => 'actionSection',
    ]); 
    switch ($model->action) {
        case "sms":
            echo $this->render('form_part_sms');
            break;
        case "subscribe":
            echo $this->render('form_part_subscribe');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    Pjax::end(); 
    ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать так, что бы при изменении аттрибута модели подгружалась необходимая часть формы через Pjax. Через нажатия на ссылку без проблем это получается сделать, а как использовать change на dropdown не могу понять.

Подскажите, как сказать Pjax, что бы он подгружал нужный url по change в select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дополнил select параметрами для pjax:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'action')
        ->dropDownList([
            'sms' => 'Отправить SMS',
            'subscribe' => 'Подписка на контент'
        ], [
            'id' => 'action',
            'data-pjax-options' => [
                'sms' => [
                    'url' => Url::to(['controller/update-part', 'id' => $model->id, 'part' => 'sms']),
                ],
                'subscribe' => [
                    'url' => Url::to(['controller/update-part', 'id' => $model->id, 'part' => 'subscribe']),
                ],
            ],
        ]); ?>
```

И добавил вот такой JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#action').change(function(){
        let options = $(this)
            .data('pjax-options')[$(this).find('option:selected').val()];
        options.container = '#actionSection';
        options.replace = false; // По-умолчанию true, из-за чего в строке браузера изменяется url
        $.pjax.reload(options);
    });
});
```

И вот такой action в контроллер:

```
/**
 * @param $part
 * @param null $id
 * @return string
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function actionUpdatePart($part, $id = null)
{
    if (is_null($id)) {
        $model = new Model();
    } else if (!$model = Model::find()->where('id = :id', ['id' => $id])->one()) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("...");
    }

    return $this->renderPartial('controller/form_part_' . $part, [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Таким образом все заработало, на change в селекте подгружается нужная часть формы.